# Received in ModelAttribute model updates existing database record instead of creating a new one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Why AgentController code update existing record instead of creating a new one but same code in CountryController works fine?

Country Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/country/add")
public String addNewCountry(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("country", new Country());
    return "country/add";
}

@PostMapping("/country")
public String createCountry(@ModelAttribute Country country){
    countriesRepository.save(country);
    return "redirect:/countries";
}
```

Country HTML Form:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/country}" th:object="${country}" method="post">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

Agent HTML Form:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{'/country/{id}/agents/new'(id=${country_id})}" th:object="${agent}" method="post">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{first_name}" /></p>
        <p>Surname: <input type="text" th:field="*{last_name}"></p>
        <p>Documents: <input type="text" th:field="*{documents}" /></p>
        <p>People recruited: <input type="text" th:field="*{people_recruited}"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

Agent Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/country/{id}/agent/add")
public String addNewAgent(@PathVariable(name = "id") String countryId, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("country_id", countryId);
    model.addAttribute("agent", new Agent());
    return "agent/add";
}

@PostMapping("/country/{id}/agents/new")
public String createAgent(@PathVariable(value = "id") String countryId, @ModelAttribute Agent agent){
    // Here i have one to many relation(one country many agents)
    return countriesRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(countryId)).map(country -> {
        agent.setCountry(country);
        agentsRepository.save(agent);
        return "redirect:/country/" + countryId + "/show/agents";
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("CountryId " + countryId + " not found"));
}
```

UPD:
If I create first agent and remove him, next create operations will work fine.

Agent class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agents")
public class Agent implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String status = "classified";

@NotNull
private String first_name;

@NotNull
private String last_name;

@NotNull
@Max(value = 2147483647)
private Integer documents;

@NotNull
@Max(value = 8)
private Integer people_recruited;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Country country;
```

Comment: This code should be working. have you autowired instance of `Agent` entity? In that case, it will update instead of creating a new record.

Comment: @AritraPaul 

    `@Autowired`
    `private AgentsRepository agentsRepository;`

    `@Autowired`
    `private CountriesRepository countriesRepository;`

Comment: May be not the solution to your problem but your  agent form action line should be as follows: `<form action="#" th:action="@{/country/{id}/agents/new(id=${country_id})}" th:object="${agent}" method="post">` Please note that there is no ' character

Comment: @Ahmet Already fix

Comment: My problem somewhere in `@Autowired private AgentsRepository agentsRepository`